# Why x variable is created and what is the logic used in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumerate

```
names = [ "Rachael Green", "Goodfellow Ian", "Tedd Crock", "Mina Joseph"]
salaries = [10260 , 41571 , 71211 , 52141 , 35781]
people_salaries = []
 
for i , j in enumerate(names):
    x = j + " $" + str(salaries[i])
    people_salaries.append(x)
```

Comment: You would have to ask the person who wrote the code why they decided to create a variable named `x`.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you about the logic used in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable x is created here to create a temporary string that will be appended to a list. Enumerate will create a tuple with a number like an index paired with every item iterated (thst is why the loop expects 2 values `(i,j)`. Then, the code will take the enumerate number and use it as an index for salaries.

I would recommend 1. creating a Dictionary with the names and salaries and 2. you don't need x for the code, just do `people_salaries.append( j + '$' + str(salaries[i]))`

Change the for loop instead of enumerate to `for i in salaries` or simply with the dictionary method

```
for i in people_dict.keys()
```

and then append with

```
people_salaries.append(i + '$' + str(people_dict[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks simple, but needs to look at implementation on enumerate:
`enumerate()` is python inbuilt module gives ability to manage indexes for lists in generator format which is memory efficient way.

Now check how enumerate is working in this case:

list(enumerate(names))

[(0, 'Rachael Green'),
(1, 'Goodfellow Ian'),
(2, 'Tedd Crock'),
(3, 'Mina Joseph')]

- Its a list of tuples with indexes assigned to names list from '0'
- for loop is iterating through this list and creating a string[here in 'x'] which tags Name against salary
- Appends empty list 'people_salaries'

Finally you will have list 'people_salaries' with Names and salary mentioned

Comment: Noep, Sorry but in the above code tuple is not given and final result will in list as he is appending all the string to   `people_salaries ` list.

Answer (score 0):

In above code,

```
names = [ "Rachael Green", "Goodfellow Ian", "Tedd Crock", "Mina Joseph"]
salaries = [10260 , 41571 , 71211 , 52141 , 35781]
people_salaries = []
 
for i , j in enumerate(names):
    x = j + " $" + str(salaries[i])
    people_salaries.append(x)
```

from for loop explaination:

```
for i , j in enumerate(names): 
  # this enumerate defragment the items of the list you give here name has several             
  # name and all the names will will be passed to j one by one and
  #  index value will be passed to i

x = j + " $" + str(salaries[i])
  # In this statemnt x is string value in which name and salary along with us currency 
  #is assigned. 
  #for eg: in first iteration 
  # x = "Rachael Green" + "$" + str(10260)
```

Now in last statement :

```
  people_salaries.append(x) # in this all x string will be appended
```

this happens through out the end of names